# Passing URI segments into Codeigniter functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's say I have a `view` method that receives a variable via the URI.

ex. http://www.domain.com/item/view/200

Does it make sense to turn the incoming variable into the correct type? In this case, making `$item_id` into `int` which is what is expected.

For example, in the controller ...

```
function view($item_id) {
    if ( $this->item_model->checkItem( (int) $item_id )) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yeah, casting the variable as integer like you are doing is OK.

And the way to pass the segment into function is like

```
$segment = $this->uri->segment(2); //get the second segmention
           // ^ You can send a default Values as well if itemid is not set
           // Like: $this -> uri -> segment(2, '0')
//now pass it to the function you need
```

Comment: Also you can add second parameter in case view id is not set. like:  $this->uri->segment(2, 0);

Comment: Doesn't it get passed automatically? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri